# How to close only current window of Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor

When I close Atom wiht <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> it closes all open windows. 
How do I close just one window? 
How do I do it using the mentioned keyboard shortcut (change the shortcut behavior)?

Comment: PS: I figgured the answer along the way, but I'll let someone else answer it as I didn't find this Q&A here and there is many hungry wolves around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the window you want to close and type this command : `ctrl-shift-w`. You can find various `atom` commands at this repository : [Atom Keyboard Shortcuts](https://github.com/nwinkler/atom-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: There it is. SO didn't allow me to do it straight away so I went for a lunch first ;) Also we should mention, that you can always find any keyboard shortcut in Command Palette under `Ctrl+Shift+P`. I have some shortcuts changed by plugins which is reflected there.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Shift+w` in Windows and Linux system.

You can find all the shortcuts here
https://github.com/nwinkler/atom-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

To close a tab use: `CTRL+W` on windows/linux and `CMD+W` on Mac.

Comment: Hey, I don't mean a tab, I mean one whole window.